# Let $\{f_n(x)\}$ be a sequence of polynomials defined as $f_1(x) = (x - 2)^2$, $f_{n+1}(x) = (f_n(x) - 2)^2$; $n \ge 1$.

Tags: polynomials

Let $\{f_n(x)\}$ be a sequence of polynomials defined as

$$f_1(x) = (x - 2)^2$$

$f_{n+1}(x) = (f_n(x) - 2)^2$;   $n \ge 1$.
How to find the constant term and the coefficient of $x$
in $f_n(x)$.